# Mongodb replica sets: why does my master server occupy more disk space than my slave?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, replication

I have two servers on my replica set. Let's call it the master and the slave, for the purpose of this discussion.

The master was the original one, and the slave was replicated from that master. At the moment of the replication, they took about the same disk space.

On month later, this is the current status.

Master:

```
user@ines:/var/lib/mongodb$ ls -al
total 44265576
drwxr-xr-x  4 mongodb mongodb       4096 Apr 22 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 root    root          4096 Jan 28 12:08 ..
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Mar 31 15:23 admin.0
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  134217728 Nov 29 12:33 admin.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Mar 31 15:23 admin.ns
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb       4096 Apr 24 08:35 journal
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Apr 17 10:33 local.0
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Mar 31 11:21 local.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 local.2
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Apr 24 11:02 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mongodb mongodb          5 Apr 17 10:32 mongod.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb nogroup       4096 Apr 22 14:40 _tmp
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Apr 24 10:39 tracking.0
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  134217728 Apr 16 14:50 tracking.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 02:26 tracking.10
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 21 04:38 tracking.11
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 11 05:30 tracking.12
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr  8 13:25 tracking.13
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 17 15:17 tracking.14
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.15
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.16
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 14 19:00 tracking.17
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 02:26 tracking.18
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 22 12:33 tracking.19
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  268435456 Apr 16 14:50 tracking.2
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 24 11:00 tracking.20
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 24 11:01 tracking.21
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 22 14:40 tracking.22
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  536870912 Apr 16 14:50 tracking.3
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 1073741824 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.4
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 10:50 tracking.5
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 21 20:26 tracking.6
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.7
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 16 16:17 tracking.8
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.9
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.ns
```

And the slave:

```
user@juliana:/var/lib/mongodb$ ls -al
total 31688800
drwxr-xr-x  4 mongodb mongodb       4096 Apr 23 17:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 root    root          4096 Mar 31 16:04 ..
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Mar 31 15:28 admin.0
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  134217728 Mar 31 15:28 admin.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Mar 31 15:28 admin.ns
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb       4096 Apr 24 10:04 journal
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Apr 17 14:19 local.0
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 local.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 local.2
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Apr 24 11:02 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mongodb mongodb          5 Apr 17 14:19 mongod.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb nogroup       4096 Apr 23 17:40 _tmp
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Apr 17 14:43 tracking.0
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  134217728 Mar 31 15:30 tracking.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.10
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.11
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 02:26 tracking.12
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.13
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 24 05:40 tracking.14
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.15
-rw-------  1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 Apr 23 17:40 tracking.16
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  268435456 Mar 31 15:30 tracking.2
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  536870912 Mar 31 15:30 tracking.3
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 1073741824 Apr 24 10:39 tracking.4
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 15 17:18 tracking.5
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 21 03:56 tracking.6
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 10:55 tracking.7
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 21 20:26 tracking.8
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.9
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Apr 24 11:02 tracking.ns
```

Is this normal? How can I reclaim the space the "master" is wasting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at that [repairDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) command.

## It is blocking the mongod no traffic will be served

, so before you issue it on the primary/master node, issue a [stepDown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/), that the other/secondary/slave node will take over the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

- Is it the same version of Mongo on both servers?
- Record Padding : http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/record-padding/

  **No Padding Allocation Strategy**

  *Changed in version 3.0.0.*

  For collections whose workloads do not change the document sizes, such as workloads that consist of insert-only operations or update operations that do not increase document size (such as incrementing a counter), you can disable the power of 2 allocation using the collMod command with the noPadding flag or the db.createCollection() method with the noPadding option.

  Prior to version 3.0.0, MongoDB used an allocation strategy that included a dynamically calculated padding as a factor of the document size.